# Change of the password is not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have CI application which has change password functionality but somehow its returning nothing. Below is code which I have written:

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Password extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('person_model','person');
        $this->load->model('password_model');
        //$this->load->model('invoice_model','invoice');
    }

    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->view('manpass');
    }

    public function edit_password()
{
    $uderid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    // update data

    if($_POST)
    {
        if($this->input->post('old_password')!=''){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password','Old password',  'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags |callback_oldpass_check');            
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password','New password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags|min_length['.PASS_MIN_LEN.']|md5');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags|min_length['.PASS_MIN_LEN.']|matches[new_password]|md5');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
            {       
                $data =array( 'password' => $this->input->post('conf_password'));                   
                $this->main->update('user','user_id',$uderid,$data);

                $this->change_password('Password updated successfully');                      
            }
            else{
                $this->change_password();
                }       
            }

        else{
            redirect(base_url().'user' , '301');
        }
    }       
    var_dump();
}

 function oldpass_check($oldpass)
 {  
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $result = $this->main->check_oldpassword($oldpass,$user_id);       
        if($result ==0)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('oldpass_check', "%s doesn't match.");
                return FALSE ;  

            }
         else
            {
                return TRUE ;

            }             
}
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Password_model extends CI_Model {

public function check_oldpassword($oldpass,$user_id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($oldpass));        
    $query = $this->db->get('user'); //data table
    return $query->num_rows(); 
}


}
```

**View**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
                  <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                      <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Password Management</li>
                  </ol>
                  <!-- Change Password-->
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <form role="form" name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Old Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="old_password" id="old_password"  class="form-control">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>New Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="new_password" id="new_password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="conf_password" id="conf_password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
                            <button type="reset" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid-->
                <!-- /.content-wrapper-->
               </div>
            </div>
```

I am not sure where I am missing the link and where the data flow is missing. Please help. The loader is loading the correct form but its nopt displaying any error message whcih i have included in controller

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords very insecure these days use the current password hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create passwords and to verify them use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: will take care of that however as of now need help in changing the password

Comment: What is returning nothing?

Comment: You also have a space in your pipe separated string near `encode_php_tags |callback_oldpass_check`

Comment: the array is not returning any values

Comment: i see only one array `$data =array( 'password' => $this->input->post('conf_password'));` and i don't think  that's what you are referring to. you are going to have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: also this line `$this->main->check_oldpassword` doesn't make any sense and you never aliased your `password_model` as main in the above code like `$this->load->model('password_model', 'main');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Controller:

```
public function changepasword(){
    $new = $this->input->post('new');
    $old = $this->input->post('old');
    $update_array = array(

        'password' => $new,
    );

    $res = $this->common->update_data($update_array, 'tablename', 'admin_id', $userdata['admin_id']);


    if ($res) {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Password Change successfully');

        redirect('changepassword', 'refresh');

    } else {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'There occur some problem! Try later!');

        redirect('changepassword', 'refresh');

    }
}
```

Model:

```
function update_data($data, $tablename, $columnname, $columnid)
{
    $this->db->where($columnname, $columnid);
    if ($this->db->update($tablename, $data)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code`<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
<a href ="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>', '</div>'); ?>` after `<div class="row">`.